# Web languages, "directory/file.extension" vs "/directory/file.extension"

Tags: php, javascript, html, relative-path

I noticed today just by chance that sometimes I write "/directory/file.extension" instead of "directory/file.extension" and that both seem to work sometimes. It seemed as though "directory/file.extension" worked every time among HTML, JavaScript, and PHP. In some cases, PHP did not like "/directory/file.extension" such as when using `include`.

In general is it better not to use the forward slash among HTML, JavaScript, and PHP? Does it matter for HTML and JavaScript?

I'm looking for an explanation as to why or why not more so than just a confirmation.

Comment: You got one of the tags right. One is a relative path and one is an absolute path.

Comment: Didn't realize that a path starting with `/` was still absolute even without `http://domain`, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a path doesn't begin with `/` it is a *relative* URL. This means that the actual pathname is determined based on the URL of the document that contains the URL. So if you have a page with URL `/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.extension`, and it contains a link to `directory/file2.ext2`, clicking on the link will go to `/dir1/dir2/dir3/directory/file2.ext2`. But if that same link were in a page with URL `/dir1/file.extension` it would go to `/dir1/directory/file2.ext2`.

Relative URLs are useful when you have a collection of pages that you want to move around as a unit, such as copying them from a development environment to production. As long as the relationships between all the files stay the same, the links between them will work.

If the path begins with `/`, it's called an *absolute* URL (strictly speaking, it should also contain the protocol, such as `http:`, and the server name `//www.company.com`). It will be interpreted from the server's document root, no matter where the link appears. Absolute URLs are useful for referencing files that are not part of the same collection. For instance, you might have a Javascript library that's used by pages at various levels in your document hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you. In my case the files I was working with were at the root so I guess `include` with the `/` needed the protocol and server name before it to work but worked fine without the `/`.

Comment: @asimes: Your guess is wrong. It's because the path beginning with `/` assumes you're opening a file under your docroot. For example, you have a file `/var/www/fruit/mango.php` and it includes `/orange.php` and your docroot is `/var/www`. PHP will try to open `/var/www/orange.php` which doesn't exist. But if it includes `orange.php` instead (no `/`) then php will try to open `/var/www/fruit/orange.php` which does exist.

Comment: So then is `/` the same as `./`?

Comment: Yes, they're equivalent. It's just like typing pathnames on Unix -- the directory of the URL is analogous to the working directory.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm going to stick with the relative ones but good to know